# Implenting wireless mobility and new protocol in NS2

Tags: protocols, ns2, wifi, aaa-security-protocol

I'm new in **NS2** programming, I need to simulate an wireless system with mobile nodes and an AAA server, any file, link or suggestion would be wonderful. I want to purpose new protocol in **NS2** like the *802.11*.
Do we need to change all AODV to new name for example?

Thanks

Comment: I found what I was seeking for in here:
down vote
accept
 

I'd found this great implementation of protocol in NS2 by Ding, Yi :

Handover security skeleton implementation for ns-2 EAP-AKA-ERP

References

RFC 4187, RFC 5296, RFC 5448

The technical details are described in this Master's thesis:

https://helda.helsinki.fi/handle/10138/36212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posts by knudfl on www.linuxquestions.com would hopefully be of help.

Regards

Comment: I found what I was seeking for in here: down vote accept I'd found this great implementation of protocol in NS2 by Ding, Yi : Handover security skeleton implementation for ns-2 EAP-AKA-ERP References RFC 4187, RFC 5296, RFC 5448 The technical details are described in this Master's thesis: helda.helsinki.fi/handle/10138/36212